# ZBar SDK integration with IOS

Tags: ios

i have recently downloaded ZBar SDK, and now wanted to scan barcode, but in tutorial and also in sample application there is need to display ZBarReaderViewController in modalview, to get it ready for scan. is there any way to read barcode without showing zbarviewcontroller, lets say do it in something in background mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to show that ViewController at all, what you need is the UIView subclass: ZBarReaderView. You can show that as a subview of any view controller root's view. If you want to make it invisible to the user you could add the view and then use the start and stop methods to start to capturing, and simply overlay something on top of this view so the camera capture is not visible to the users.

Hope that helps.

Comment: start and stop method from which object ? i want it in background mode because in general view i have UITableView with list of barcode data.
and want to select the appropriate row when reader find it.

Comment: @Taffarel From the ZBarReaderView object, see my updated reply.